# get information from connectedComponentsWithStats in opencv via c++

Tags: opencv, visual-c++

I want to get area , height , weight , centriod , left and right of objects in image  by connectedComponentsWithStats in opencv!
but I dont know how to use this function(connectedComponentsWithStats) and get properties of that.
imagine i have the following picture
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QD59i.png)
as you can see there are 3 objects , I want cordinates and property of these objects.
would you say an simple example to how to do it
thank you all for your attention

Comment: You may try something as simple as: http://opencvexamples.blogspot.com/2013/09/find-contour.html

Comment: but this link doesn't exist

Comment: Then search for something like Opencv Contour detection example